# How to know how many resources a process uses in all its execution time? linux

Tags: resources

I would like to know if there is a program to analyze how many resources it takes to execute a command.
for example as follows:

```
# magic_program python3 app.py
```

And that the program tells you how many resources the execution of a program uses, the use of cpu, memory, disk, network, etc.

that in a certain way watches over the program during execution and then gives you a report. If it doesn't exist, I would love to carry out a project like this.

#### Questions

Is there this magic program? if not, how viable would its creation be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [time](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time) program will collect and report CPU, memory, disk and socket I/O stats, which is pretty close to what you are asking.